# retrieve subset of string with regex - python

Tags: python, regex, string

```
p = "\home\gef\Documents\abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar"
```

I'm looking for a way to retrieve `this_word`.

```
base = os.path.basename(p)
base1 = base.replace("abc_","")
base1.replace("_dfg.gz.tar","")
```

this works, but it's not ideal because I would need to know in advance what strings I want to remove. Maybe a `regex` would be appropriate here?

Comment: If you want to use a regex, what are the rules? Please share your attempt to see what your logic is.

Comment: Is there a rule or logic to it to match `this_word`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information, but from what is shown can't you just use string slicing?

Maybe like this:

```
>>> p = os.path.join('home', 'gef', 'Documents', 'abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar')
>>> p
'home/gef/Documents/abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar'
>>> os.path.dirname(p)
'home/gef/Documents'
>>> os.path.basename(p)
'abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar'
>>> os.path.basename(p)[4:-11]
'this_word'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information, but from what is shown can't you just split on `_` chars?

Maybe like this:

```
>>> p = os.path.join('home', 'gef', 'Documents', 'abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar')
>>> p
'home/gef/Documents/abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar'
>>> os.path.dirname(p)
'home/gef/Documents'
>>> os.path.basename(p)
'abc_this_word_dfg.gz.tar'
>>> '_'.join(
...     os.path.basename(p).split('_')[1:-1])
'this_word'
```

It splits by underscores, then discards the first and last part, finally joining the other parts together with underscore (if `this_word` had no underscores, then there will be only one part left and no joining will be done).